# Como configurar CodeIgniter 4 para usar en un dominio

Tags: codeigniter-4

Estoy trabajando con CodeIgniter 4.1.3 y necesito poder configurarlo para acceder como un dominio de la forma,
http://proyecto.hcsm.grm.sld.cu/ por ejemplo.
Y no de la forma local, http://localhost/proyecto/
saludos equipo

Comment: Tu dominio está en linea o es local? Ya que si es local debes configurar un `VirtualHost` en Apache Server con ese nombre y despues en `config.php`

Comment: gracias, ya resolvi, tuve que editar el archivo httpd.conf del servidor de apache, el httpd-vhosts.conf para crear un host virtual tambien de apache, el archivo hosts de windows y al editar el Alias del proyecto agregar esto: Require all granted y cometar #Require local, saludos

Answer (score 0):

En la ruta

> config > config.php

configura

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://proyecto.hcsm.grm.sld.cu/";
```